# Use Remove-Item in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but i still didn't found an answer.

I try to Remove a Folder with some Scripts inside.

Folder is in :  C:\Public\Folder

Inside the Folder are 7 Scripts.

The Script CopyFiles.ps1, copies 4 of them to a different Location.

After the Copy, it Removes the Folder itself with all the other Files.

Script looks like this :

```
[string] $Path = "";
[string] $Destination = "";

# Copy the Folder
[string] $Destination = "C:\ProgramData\Path\To\Folder";
[string] $Path = "C:\Public\Folder";

Copy-Item -Path $Path -Destination $Destination

#Copy Files
[string[]] $Files = ("CreateUser.ps1", "RemoveFiles.ps1", "RemoveUser.ps1", "UpdateUser.ps1");

foreach($file in $Files)
{
    $Script = $Path + "\" + $file
    write-host $Script
    Copy-Item -Path $Script -Destination $Destination
}


[string] $Path = "C:\Public";

Remove-Item -Path $Path -Include *UserManager* -Recurse -Force
```

So far this Script worked like a charm.
But today not.
Im getting following Error Message :

> Remove-Item : Cannot remove the item at 'C:\Public' because it is in use.
> At C:\Public\Folder\CopyFiles.ps1:24 char:1

Which also make totally sense, since its in use, it cannot get deletetd.
But why did it work till now?

Comment: If your current directory at the time you run the script is `C:\PUBLIC`, that's the reason for the "in use" message. If your previous runs were with your current directory set to something else, the script will have worked.

Comment: Ahh that makes totally sense.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `Set-Location` (`cd`) outside of the folder you are trying to delete. A shell will have an open handle on a folder if that folder is its present working directory.

You don't necessarily need to `Set-Location` from the script (though you could), just don't invoke the script with `C:\Public\Folder` set as the working directory.

In the case you are not in that folder, you will have to determine what process is locking the folder. I have never done this programmatically, but the tool I generally use for this is [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/index.htm). If you have [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), you can easily install it with:

```
choco install lockhunter
```

---

### Additional Reading

I have not attempted this yet, but curiosity finally got the best of me on this topic and I found a [Hey, Scripting Guy! article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-determine-process-that-locks-a-file/) about using `P/Invoke` to call the necessary Win32 API functions which can tell you which process is locking a file. You may find this useful to read. From the article, it looks like the key Win32 API functions in scope are:

- `NtQuerySystemInformation`: Amongst other things, can query the handles open on the system.
- `NtQueryObject`: Queries additional information about a handle.
- `OpenProcess`: Allows us to get more information about the process that owns the handle.
- `DuplicateHandle`: Creates a copy of a handle in the current process (for example, ISE) so we can perform additional operations on it.
- `QueryDosDevice`: Converts a logical drive (such as drive C) into the DOS device identifier.

Comment: Thy for your answer :) will look into it :)

Comment: I added some additional information about the Win32 API functions reportedly required to identify the locking process with PowerShell. You may find it useful or interesting to read if you wish to attempt such a detection.